# WebView inside ScrollView seems to work fine, but warnings to not use - alternative?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-scrollview

Everything I've read (AFTER already making my app :( ) says something like "you should never use a WebView inside a ScrollView!".  This is understandable because you could theoretically have 2 scrolling things which would make for odd usability.

But - so far, I've seen no adverse effects.  Then again, each WebView I'm using doesn't require scrolling - maybe that makes it acceptable-use even though it's technically wrong?

Are there adverse effects that I'm just not noticing to due lack of testing on a specific version(s)?

If I can't use a WebView inside a ScrollView, how would I get the below layout (my current app):

```
LinearLayout
    ScrollView
        LinearLayout
            TextView //Title of article
            TextView //Subtitle of article
            RelativeLayout
                ImageView //Large Image (clickable to gallery)
                ImageView //"more photos icon"
            WebView // a small horizontal ad
            TextView // actual article text
            WebView //embedded HTML code ranging from iframe to video...etc
            WebView //embedded HTML code ranging from iframe to video...etc
            WebView // a small horizontal ad
            LinearLayout
                TextView //DB-driven "similar articles" list
            WebView //disqus comments
```

Note: I realize it's "wrong" - but so are using `<center>` tags in HTML, and people still use them all the time effectively.  The difference seems to be that there's an easy-and-better alternative to `<center>` - is there something similar for this scenario in Android?  A somewhat-simple way to get the above?

Answer (score 4):

> This is understandable because you could theoretically have 2 scrolling things which would make for odd usability.

More specifically, `ScrollView` is as dumb as a box of rocks, and assumes it has full control over scrolling.

> Then again, each WebView I'm using doesn't require scrolling

More accurately, it doesn't require scrolling on the devices that you have tested, and for the content that you have tested.

For example, DISQUS comment threads typically require scrolling *on a desktop browser*. One imagines that there will be comment threads that will be long enough to require scrolling on a mobile device, unless there is a scroll-free DISQUS embed you can use.

> If I can't use a WebView inside a ScrollView, how would I get the below layout (my current app):

Get rid of everything and have a single `WebView`, with generated HTML content that contains all the stuff in your current structure. IOW, do what you would do in a Web site.

Comment: When I have ImageViews, it's quite easy to do click detection... if they're HTML, how would I handle that?

Comment: (the disqus code I'm using appears to be scroll-free, as there are many many comments, and still no scroll - though I still like the idea of using all generated HTML - just not sure about a few things like image clicks...etc)

Comment: @Dave: "if they're HTML, how would I handle that?" -- ummm... `onclick` attributes, calling out to Java objects injected via `addJavaScriptInterface()`, would be where I'd start.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use WebView.
Ads you can attach to application or use AdMob.
To video is VideoView.
Alternative to comments webview is make api (using php [POST] and sql).
Using webview isn't comlulsory.
I hope I helped

Comment: Admob is for Google specifically - we're not serving ads through them.    Comments are through Disqus, which has HTML code to implement.  I appreciate your time, but I don't believe this is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Placing the WebView in a ScrollView will work as long as the WebView isn't internally scrollable in the same direction as the ScrollView. Making the WebView not scroll internally can be achieved in a couple of ways:

- the WebView's height (assuming the ScrollView is scrollable vertically) is WRAP_CONTENT,
- the WebView has a fixed size and the content has reactive layout which will never be larger than the viewport (alternatively "overflow: hidden" could be used).

I don't think the above approaches will mix well with pinch-zooming so you'd best not enable that.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Java class and extends with WebView

```
package com.mypackage.common.custom.android.widgets

public class TouchyWebView extends WebView {

     public TouchyWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
     }

    public TouchyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

  public TouchyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
     super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
     requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
     return super.onTouchEvent(event);
  }          
}
```

and in layout

```
<com.mypackage.common.custom.android.widgets
      android:id="@+id/webView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

I hope this will solve your problem